# Does it necessarily follow that $C^{n, \gamma}(\overline{X})$ is a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $X$ denote an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $n \in \{0, 1, \dots\}$, $0 < \gamma \le 1$. Does it necessarily follow that $C^{n, \gamma}(\overline{X})$ is a Banach space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space please explain your notation and see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When 0 < p < 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_0_.3C_p_.3C_1)

Comment: I didn't know those, and it is said that it is a Banach space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition#H.C3.B6lder_spaces if $X$ is bounded